# Is there a real function such that the difference of its values at distinct points is bounded from below?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $M>0$ such that $d(f(x),f(y))>M$ whenever $x\neq y$?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: No. For $k\in\Bbb Z$ let $A_k=\{x\in\Bbb R:kM\le f(x)<(k+1)M\}$. Now apply the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: So basically, each $A_{k}$ should have at most one element, but we also have $\bigcup \limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} A_{k} = \Bbb R$, but the LHS is countable and the RHS is uncountable, which means such an $f$ doesn't exist.  Is that right?

Comment: @user46944: That’s right.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You would need uncountably many real numbers (function values) such that any two of them are at least $M$ apart.